# Rails ActiveAdmin with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, carrierwave

I am using ActiveAdmin with rails 4 and it is working fine. When I add an item, I am taken to the index page listing the new item/items and the filters on the right side. Also, there are the email and logout links at the top right.

My issue is when I add an item with an image the filters, email and logout links disappear.

If I delete the item with the image they appear again. I can add /new to the url and it still takes me to the form but I am trying to figure out why adding a picture removes the links.

here is my form:

```
form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
f.inputs "Size" do
  f.input :title
  f.input :description
  f.input :price
  f.input :image, :as => :file
  f.input :developer_days
  f.input :designer_days
  f.input :name
end
f.actions
end
```

I just can't figure out why this happens.

Comment: I used Carrierwave in my Rails 4 project, it's working fine though. What's the version of your Active Admin? I think it's better to file an issue in the Github repo.

Comment: I am using     gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'. I'll do that then thank you.